# How to distribute the items of a menu equally?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have a menu as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionOrdenesMenuPedido"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/item_ordenes"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_carrito"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tituloMenuPedido"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/item_orden"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionGuardarMenuPedido"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="@string/item_guardar"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_guardar"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionCancelarMenuPedido"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:title="@string/btn_cancelar"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_eliminar"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

[image]

I have retired the title as follows:

```html
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

and when the application works it looks like this:

[image]

My question is: Is there a way that the items are not on the left, that is, distributed evenly across the width?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with build in Action bar menu. You need to add view inside `ToolBar`.  IMHO do not break the material design guidelines.

Comment: I could use an AppBarLayout to place buttons symmetrically, but the problem is that there is a DrawerLayout (NavigationView) which uses the menu indicated above.